# revert 'php artisan serve' command in laravel

Tags: php, apache, command-line, laravel

I have a laravel app. I ran `'php artisan serve'` command for local testing and my app was served at **localhost:8000**. But now I want to stop serving it at **localhost:8000** ie., I want it not to serve now.

I closed the command line, restarted the server but it is still serving. How can it be done?

**Note:** I am using windows for testing purposes.

Comment: Are you running Windows?

Comment: u have to stop the server from cmd/terminal before closing it

Comment: for mac users, try `control + C` instead of `command + C`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `ESC`. Locate the php process running artisan and kill it with *right click* -> `kill process`.

Reopen the command-line and start back the server.

Note that you should be able to kill the process just by sending it a kill signal with `Ctrl` + `C`.

Comment: is there no way to do it from cmd?

Comment: How about `Ctrl` + `D`?

Comment: when it serving, it prints messages to command prompt, such as [Sun Nov 16 23:53:47 2014] ::1:51990 [200]: /favicon.ico. if you hit ctrl + c, it will stop and serving will be terminated, that is you cant access localhost:8000 anymore

Answer (score 52):

here is what i do 
press `ctrl`+ `c`

```
> lsof -i :8000
```

to check if the port is busy or not  if any process is listening to the port 8000 it will be displayed with port id

```
> sudo  kill -9 [PID]
```

kill the process that listen to that port id

run lsof agin

```
> sudo lsof -i 8000
```

vola

Answer (score 12):

I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in my mac for stop the command php artisan laravel serve

Answer (score 8):

For windows user, type this command for showing the list of current running php artisan process:

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq php.exe"
```

Will show:

```
Image Name ---- PID ---- Session Name ---- Session ---- Mem Usage

php.exe --------- XXXX ---- Console ----------  4 ------- 19.852 K
```

Look up PID number (XXXX), and type this to kill the process:

```
taskkill /F /PID XXXX
```

Answer (score 6):

When I use **cygwin** to run my `php artisan serve` on Windows machine, pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> does not kill the process. To stop it, use @jsalonen's solution. Basically you are looking for this then kill it:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Windows 10 with XAMPP server depending on what shell you use to run:

```
php artisan serve
```

In Windows CMD: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
In XAMPP Shell: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd>
In Ubuntu and RedHat/CentOS terminal  it's: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

This work for me.

`sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:port_number)`

Comment: For anyone trying to do this via the CLI: this is simple and works great!

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pause|Break</kbd> should do it for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If your using VS Code, simply do the following:

1. Open VS Code terminal
2. Find the drop down box that displays a list of all the running shells
3. Select "php" from the list and click the garbage bin icon

This deletes the shell and kills the server.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows CMD or smder: CTRL + C